# How can i retrain a loaded keras model with new data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a model that is saved, i have it's labels transformed to numbers, for example, 0, 1, 2, 3 for certain strings, this was done automatically during training. Now i have new data i want to put in because i am getting false positives, and i want to set those false positives straight by assigning them as new data with a certain label to alter the model to see it properly. However i have absolutely no idea how to do this. I tried adding the new x_train and y_train data but i just get a bunch of weirdly high loss and accuracy of 1.0 forever before it ends.
I could really need help because i don't want to have to keep training the model entirely over again.

See below, i set 'y' as containing the label for the new data, and 'x' as containing everthing but the label, then i wanted to transform the new data 'x' with the previous models scaler 'sc'. Is this correct? Then

```
LinuxGoodData = pd.read_csv('New Data', sep=r'\s*,\s*', engine='python')
LinuxGoodData['Label']= label_encoder.fit_transform(LinuxGoodData['Label'])
y = LinuxGoodData[['Label']]

x = pd.get_dummies(LinuxGoodData.drop(['Label', ], axis = 1))
#sc = MinMaxScaler()
sc = joblib.load('scaler_transform2023.joblib')

x = sc.fit_transform(x)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

model = keras.models.load_model("mymodel.h5")

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250, verbose=1)

model.save("mymodel2.h5")
saved_model = keras.models.load_model("mymodel2.h5")
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIeRX.png)

I hope i explained it well enough in the body.

Comment: You should not fit your previous scaler again. `x = sc.fit_transform(x)` will fit ,then will transform it. Use `x = sc.transform(x)` instead. But i am not sure this is enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i'll make that change now!